# Accessing data set by React Hook in a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a little new to React. I am trying to make a GET request from a REST API endpoint that should return the following JSON:

```
{
    "author": "aqho",
    "title": "Second post!",
    "slug": "second-post",
    "body": "Let's see if things get updated in the database like the slug",
    "comments_list": [
        {
            "author": "aqho",
            "body": "it works!",
            "slug": "7213569934952552711-3"
        },
        {
            "author": "bobglu",
            "body": "how are you just so classically handsome",
            "slug": "2029512273124111200-4"
        }
    ]
}
```

To query the API, I use the following code:

```
const PostDetailPage = (props) => {
    const [post, setPost] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const slug = props.match.params.slug;
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await API.get(`posts/${slug}`);
                setPost(res.data);
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        };
        
        fetchData();
    }, []);
...
}
```

I want to create a function that returns a list of the comments from the JSON. My initial attempt was the following:

```
const renderComments = () => {
        return post.comments_list.map(item => (
          <li 
            key={item.slug}
          >
            {item.body}
          </li>
        ));
      };
```

However, it gives me the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Looking online, it seems that most people's issues can be solved by setting the default value to an empty dictionary, but I already did that in my React hook. I'm very confused about why posts.comments_list is undefined. I also noticed that trying to log the title of the post using console.log(post.title) gives me `undefined` as well. I'm a little confused why this is, because the following code is able to pull the values from `post` perfectly fine:

```
const PostDetailPage = (props) => {
...
    return (
            <div id='post-details-page'>
                <div id='post-details'>
                    <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                    <h4>Published on: {post.published_on}</h4>
                    <h4>Last edited: {post.last_edited}</h4>
                    <p> {post.body} </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
};

export default PostDetailPage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const renderComments = () => {
        return post.comments_list?.map(item => (
          <li 
            key={item.slug}
          >
            {item.body}
          </li>
        ));
      };
```

on first render, post = {}, post.comments_list is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add check `post` and `post.comments_list` object because initially it is empty

```
const renderComments = () => {
        return post && post.comments_list &&post.comments_list.map(item => (
          <li 
            key={item.slug}
          >
            {item.body}
          </li>
        ));
      };
```